# Customizing the Format Windows Phone App

Tags: c#, windows, windows-phone-8, format

How or what should I used on my Windows Phone Application to customize the Format of the app so I can use any Windows Phone without changing the design every time

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using Xamarin.Forms but keep Windows 10 in mind.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/windows/